# Is there a mistake regarding subject-verb agreement?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, subject-verb-agreement

> **Increased financial support** could help to raise the quality of locally made films and **allow** them to compete with the foreign productions that currently dominate the market.

*quoted from* http://ielts-simon.com/ielts-help-and-english-pr/2015/06/ielts-writing-task-2-foreign-films-essay.html

Have an author made a slip not using the verb in an agreement with the subject, or there's something that I'm missing out, misreading?

Comment: *Allow* is infinitive, the complement of *could*: "Increased financial support could ... allow them to compete."

Comment: You'd be more likely to reverse the two effects if ***could*** only applied to ***raising quality*** (i.e. - more money would *definitely* allow them to compete, but only *might* improve quality). But it doesn't seem so much "ungrammatical" as merely "non-idiomatic" to have ***allows*** in OP's exact context.

Comment: In your question, "Have an author..." is an error of agreement. Correct would be "Has the author...". Also "There's something..." is intended to be a question, so should be "Is there something"

Comment: @FumbleFingers do you really think *allows* in the context wouldn't be ungrammatical, despite *could*?

Comment: @Cavid Hummatov: Consider, for example, *More funding **allows** them to develop new products and **could** help raise profits next year* - which per my first comment, "reverses" the sequence in which two consequences (one "definite", the other *possible*) are presented. Note that any other differences between my version and OP's are syntactically irrelevant. I accept that *idiomatically*, few people would recast my example as  *More funding **could** help raise profits next year and  **allows** them to develop new products*, but it would be ridiculous to suppose it's "ungrammatical".

Comment: ...if you're not convinced purely because my last example above sounds "odd", consider including ***definitely*** before ***could***. Also consider how you'd rate it if the final clause were split off into a separate sentence, as *And [it] definitely allows them to develop...* Why should any of these variants stray too far from your concept of "natural English", and thereby suddenly become reclassified as "ungrammatical?

Answer (score 1):

Increased financial support could **help** to raise the quality of locally made films and **allow** them to compete with the foreign productions that currently dominate the market

*allow* is parallel with the verb *help*, they are both bare infinitives as they are the complements of "could". The meaning is "Increased financial support could ... allow (locally made films) to compete ..."